# Total Power Cutoff circuit

Tags: timer, 555, low-power, battery-operated

I'm designing a battery controlled circuit using a 555 timer to control a mosfet to provide power to a load. The problem I'm trying to solve is to reduce the current draw while the circuit is not being used to the minimum possible.

I found this question: [Low power delayed off circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/342263/low-power-delayed-off-circuit) which is close to what I am wanting to do. However, in my case, the 555 timer is the load.

The function of the circuit is that the user presses a button and power is supplied to a high current load for a set period of time of 2 minutes. Once the 2 minutes expires, power from the battery is removed from the timing circuit as well as the high current load. As the circuit is powered from a single lithium battery, the timing circuit may also need a regulator to provide high enough voltage for the timing circuit. The power to the regulator should be cut as well when the circuit isn't in use. This seems like a common problem, so maybe I'm over thinking it or just not using the correct search terms to find my solution.

At first glance, it seems like it should be straightforward - use a mosfet on the power supply between the supply and the timing circuit. While the timing circuit output is active, keep the input mosfet on to keep the timing circuit powered up. When the timing circuit becomes inactive, power is removed from the mosfet powering the timing circuit and thus the timing circuit cuts power to itself. The implementation is eluding me, however.

Comment: don't use a 555. use something like CD4047 that uses no power (2uA) when stopped. that way you can leave the power connected to th timing chip without running down your battery.

Comment: there are micropower comparators, and nanoAmp flipflop counters. Use? those?

Comment: Another issues you'll find with a 555 is that achieving a delay of more than a few seconds with an RC timed monostable is going to be very inaccurate. You could then feed the output into a counter, like a 4020, but then it's generally simpler to just use a basic microcontroller like a PIC10 or ATtiny which have sleep/standby currents under a microamp, a calibrated internal oscillator and can run directly off a single Li cell.

Comment: So far the comments match what I'm seeing. The 555 timer is the simplest method to use with regard to using basic components to latch a circuit for a predetermined amount of time and then cut power, is this accurate? Aside from maybe a time delay relay which brings other issues. If I were to use a micro controller, is there a method to emulate opening a relay to completely cut power to a circuit - including the microcontroller which controls the relay? I'd like the power losses while off to be in the lower pico to femto-amps range.